# Tab Order in Visual Studio hates me

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Tab Order in Visual Studio does not work for me for some reason.

I am making a VB.NET plugin for a cad program called Rhinocreos 5.

I have everything set perfect, and I don't know what the cause of it is.

I am using .Show() instead of .ShowDialog(), because I need that thread open and I don't feel like doing any thread management (not paid enough lol)

Does anyone have any pointers for this? Has anyone else ran into a tab problem with Rhino5 and .NET?

EDIT**
Seems I have to use a MODELESS Form for a rhino plugin.... So I wont have any tab keys or arrow keys unless I do a hook. But since I need to make the plugin future proof (in case I am no longer working here), I won't be doing that either. But thanks for the answers, comments, and awesome downvotes.

Comment: What are you expecting when you press the tab key?

Comment: Let me re do my post.... its early

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a modeless form inside of Rhino3D as a plugin.

Rhino3D uses all plugins in the main thread. So tab is not an option.

The workaround was to tag all controls with a tag work (I used "tabMe")

Then I store all the controls in a List myTabbyControls.

Each time I press tab, I would cycle through the list.

But thanks for the down votes. It's the running joke of SO.

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to guess what's going on from the information you have provided, but I'd check the following things in the following order:

1. The disobedient form is open and has focus.
2. The form has controls in it.
3. At least some of the controls are enabled, focusable have their `TabStop` set to true.
4. There is no low-level keyboard handling in action (PreviewKeyDown, hooks etc).
5. Finally I'd call `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`, passing main form as parameter (to make disobedient form a child of main form) and see if that makes a difference.